# WPF WebBrowser or Awesomium WebControl - and how to control displayed web page

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control, awesomium

Is there a way i can display web page inside WPF application with either standard WebBrowser or Awesomium WebControl and then control it. For example i would like to load google.com, enter something in search and click search. I managed to get web page source with WebBrowser but i can't modify value on search textbox. Is there any other way this can be done

Loading page like this:

```
//private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        //{
        //  this.MyPage.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
        //}
```

Getting html like this:

```
//private void MyPage_OnLoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        //{
        //  dynamic doc = MyPage.Document;
        //  dynamic htmlText = doc.documentElement.InnerHtml;
        //  string htmlstring = htmlText;
            //bool search = htmlstring.Contains("lst-ib");
            //var dom = MyPage.Document as HTMLDocument;
            //if (dom != null)
            //{
            //  var ec = dom.getElementById("lst-ib");
            //  SOMETHING TO ACCESS VALUE OF lst-ib AND CLICK SEARCH

            //}
          //}
```

I wasn't able to get html with awesomium and also can't find anything on how to do it, so every help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  If you host the System.Windows.Control (webbrowser) then you have to use MSHTML to get to the DOM and manipulate it.  It's fairly complex but can be done.  Look for the (scant) documentation concerning MSHTML and get ready to read about C++ interfaces.   On the other hand there is the System.Windows.Forms (webbrowser) that has a nicer C# user interface, you may want to look into it's HTMLDocument for further review.   I don't know too much about awesomium.

Comment: I managed to figure it out, thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this. Hope it helps someone

```
var htmlDoc = ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).webControl.Document as HTMLDocument;
        if (htmlDoc != null)
        {
            var userid = htmlDoc.getElementById("userid") as HTMLInputElement;
            var apikey = htmlDoc.getElementById("apikey") as HTMLInputElement;
            if (userid != null && apikey != null)
            {
                userid.value = ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).tbxApi.Text;
                apikey.value = ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).tbxVcode.Text;

                var login = htmlDoc.getElementById("login") as HTMLFormElement;
                if (login != null)
                {
                    login.submit();
                }
            }}
```